# PostgreSQL Latest Record w/o id nor date

Tags: postgresql

I have a foreign table without id nor date.
If for example other users insert a number of records, is it possible in PostgreSQL to select the last record inserted?
*Note: My only access to that table is select only

Comment: I will highly suggest you to suggest that they create either a timestamp column (or a couple of them, one for inserted time and the other for updated time) or an auto increment column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL tables represent unordered sets and the result sets too. You cannot guarantee your data without specify `ORDER BY`.

And :

> I have a foreign table without id nor date

There is no other way to workaround without this to specify what you need.

> My only access to that table is select only

If you only get just `Select` privilege you should tell your DBA you cannot give the data with 100% guarantee if that is the last data inserted from that user.

Comment: Thank you for that info. If that is the case, maybe I'll just drop the idea and think of other solutions

Answer (score 0):

Based on my knowledge PostgreSQL does not **guarantee** to preserve insertion order. Without a timestamp field or sequential primary key I do not think guaranteed fetching of the last row is possible.

You can try this

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE CTID = (SELECT MAX(CTID) FROM YOUR_TABLE)
```

provided that the target table does not do update operations.

Comment: `MAX(CTID)` does **not** mean the "latest" row.

Comment: CTID does not mean latest rather it means the last record in terms of physical location. That's why I added the 'provided' clause isn't it?

Comment: Thank you for that info. Also tried ctid approach, though it is returning that ctid cannot be referenced from that point of the query. Does this have something to do with the table being a foreign?